# Wordpress how to display all posts based on tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 3 tags:

- **Tag 1**
- **Tag 2**
- **Tag 3**

I need to display all of the posts in my `custom post type` and specified term. They need to `be sorted by tag` and hiding the tags that are not being used like this:

- **Tag 1**

  - Post A
  - Post C
- **Tag 2**

  - Post B

**But it's displaying like this:**

- **Tag 1**

  - Post A
  - Post C
- **Tag 2**

  - Post B
- **Tag 3**

  - (Empty)

Tag 3 is being displayed even though there are no posts currently using the tags...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// These 3 variables change dynamically depending on page slug.
$cpt = houses;
$tax = type;
$term = small;

$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'orderby'           => 'name',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'post_type'         => $cpt,
'tax_query'         => array(
   array(
   'taxonomy'      => $tax,
   'field'         => 'name',
   'terms'         => $term
   )
 )
);

$tags = get_tags($args); // Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3
$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
  ?>
    <h5><?php echo $tag->name.' (Tag)'; ?></h5>
  <?php
  foreach($posts as $post)
  {
    if( has_tag( $tag ) )
    {
    ?>
      <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo the_title().' (Post)';?></a><br>
    <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
  <hr>
  <?php
}
?>
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logic would be something like this:

- get_tags

  - for each tag

    - get associated posts (run `get_posts` here)
    - Only if there is any post

      - echo the title of the tag
      - for each associated post (run a foreach loop for posts here)

        - echo the title of the post

---

So you could move your `get_posts` query inside the `foreach($tags as $tag)` and use `$tag` argument to see if there are any post(s) associated with that tag.

Note that in the `$posts_args` i used an extra argument called `tag` which will do the trick for you in the `tags foreach loop`. The value of the `tag` argument is the tag slug.

> [`Tag arguments you could pass into your query`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)

Also by using `get_tags` function, you don't have to specify `orderby` or `order`, since the default value for 'orderby' is 'name', and default value for 'order' is 'ASC', so you don't need to pass them as arguments.

---

So the entire code would be something like this:

```php
$cpt = houses;
$tax = type;
$term = small;

$posts_args = array(
  'posts_per_page'    => -1,
  'orderby'           => 'name',
  'order'             => 'ASC',
  'post_type'         => $cpt,
  'tag'               => $tag->slug,
  //OR
  //'tag_slug__in'      => array($tag->slug),
  'tax_query'         => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy'      => $tax,
      'field'         => 'name',
      'terms'         => $term
    )
  )
);

$tags = get_tags(); // Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3

foreach ($tags as $tag) {

  $posts = get_posts($posts_args);

  if ($posts) { ?>

    <h5><?php echo $tag->name . ' (Tag)'; ?></h5>

    <?php

    foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>

      <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title() . ' (Post)'; ?></a><br>

    <?php

    }

    ?>

    <hr>

<?php

  }

}

?>
```

Which will output this:

```
Tag 1
  Post A
  Post C
--------
Tag 2
  Post B
```

Let me know if you could get it to work!